# JavaScript, React const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I just faced this Java Script code:

```
const {
  myKey,
  uname,
  issorted,
  title,
  hClick,
} = this.props;
```

Please tell me what this means? What are its implications?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Basically it's declaring variables from each of the provided object keys. You'll be able to access those variables like

```
console.log(uname)
```

as opposed to

```
console.log(this.props.uname)
```

In addition to this, if you're asking about 'const' as well, [this has a good explanation](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75)

Comment: Worth noting that deconstruction can be done to array arguments, it does not only occur in the example provided in the question

Answer (score 1):

It's an object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). In your code example it extracts data from `this.props` object into distinct constants declared on the left-hand side of the assignment (`myKey`, `uname`, `issorted` ...). So if `this.props` was an object like this:

```
this.props =  {
    myKey: 'value1',
    uname: 'value2',
    issorted: 'value3',
    title: 'value4',
    hClick: 'value5'
}
```

after calling mentioned code the declared constants (`myKey`, `uname`, `issorted` ...) would have values of corresponding object properties - e.g. `myKey` constant would be equal to `value1`.

In your code sample `const` tells that object data will be extracted into [constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) but of course you can also use variables declared with `let` or `var`.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Javascript, destructuring has become a popular method of accessing certain values from within objects, and localizing them.

In this case, `this.props` contains properties `myKey, uname, issorted, title, hClick`, possibly among others. In order to obtain on specific properties instead of copying the entire object, we do destructure assignment and localize each property according to their name, as shown by the code you've provided.